# Telephone keypad in java not working correctly

Tags: java

I am building a telephone keypad for a task , its written in java for studies, its working although not correctly. If i push a number it adds all numbers before the one I have pushed and it does not display the "*" or the "#" ? I would like it to work as a simple dialing keypad would , if you push 1 then it should display 1 , if you push *111*0848307927# on the keypad thats what it should display in the Textfield lcd.
Any help would go far, although I'm sure its something small that I'm missing, you guys usually help me when I'm stuck, Thanks in advanced!

```
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Telephone extends Frame implements ActionListener
  {
     Button keys[];
     Panel keypad;
     TextField lcd;
     Label value;
     boolean  foundKey;

     public Telephone()
     {
    lcd =new TextField(20);
        lcd.setEditable(false);
    keypad= new Panel ();
    keys= new Button[13];



    //construct and assign captions to the buttons
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
        keys[i] = new Button(String.valueOf(i));

    keys[10] =new Button ("*");
    keys[11] =new Button ("0");
    keys[12] =new Button ("#");


    setBackground(Color.magenta);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    keypad.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));

    //add keys
    for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)//1,2,3
                keypad.add(keys[i]);

    for (int i=4; i<=6; i++)//4,5,6
                keypad.add(keys[i]);

    for (int i=7; i<=9; i++)//7,8,9
        keypad.add(keys[i]);

    keypad.add(keys[10]);
    keypad.add(keys[11]);
    keypad.add(keys[12]);

    for (int i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
        keys[i].addActionListener(this);

    //add componets to display
    add(lcd, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(keypad,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //add()

    addWindowListener(

        new WindowAdapter()
                {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
    );

        }//constructor ends

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
    foundKey = false;
    for (int i=0; i<keys.length &&!foundKey;i++)
            {
                if(e.getSource() == keys[i])

            foundKey=true;
                switch(i)
                {
                    case 0:case 1:case 2:case 3:case 4:case 5:case 6:case 7:case 8:case 9:


                    lcd.setText(lcd.getText()+ keys[i].getLabel());
                    break;
                }//end switch
            }//end for
      }//end actionPerformed

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Telephone f = new Telephone();
        f.setTitle("Telephone Application");
        f.setBounds(50,130,250,300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
  }//class ends
```

Comment: `If i push a number it adds all numbers before the one I have pushed` and you want to add it after? You're not saying what you want to happen with this or the * and # keys.

Comment: And don't use AWT, use Swing, SWT or anything else not deprecated 15 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have written the case statement only for numbers 0 to 9. you should also handle the '#' and '*' keys. I dont see the use of switch case as you are checking for the key clicked in the "if" condtion. Replace the switch as:

```
lcd.setText(lcd.getText() + "" + keys[i].getLabel());
break;
```